# Starting process (one console application from another)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone knows why I'm getting this error (not every time but sometimes) when trying to start one console application from another.
Error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Unknown error
>   (0xfffffffe)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

this is my Code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process myProc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
try
{
    myProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\MyFolder\MyExecutableApplication.exe";
    myProc.Start();
    myProc.WaitForExit();
    procesResult = myProc.ExitCode;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    cLog.WriteLog("problem", ex.ToString(), myConfig.LogPath);
}
finally
{
    if (myProc != null)
    {
        myProc.Close();
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Are your sure MyExecutableApplication.exe works fine ? Does it require some arguments or to be started from a specific working folder ?

Comment: it doesn't require any arguments, when I start it manually everything works fine, it work fine using this code too, but sometimes i get error above :(

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's the permission problem.
Try this

```
myProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

reference from this [comments](http://codebetter.com/brendantompkins/2004/05/13/run-a-bat-file-from-asp-net/#comment-101022724)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an permission elevation problem(although I do not know the reason you get the error sometimes); try adding;

```
myProc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue. Try to turn off `UAC` and add exception to `windows defender` (or another security tool)